# How to access the Avatar from Google?

Tags: openid, google-openid

I've implemented OpenID-Login with Google. I can access the following attribute types 'contact/email', 'namePerson/first', 'namePerson/last' and 'pref/lang'. But I also wanna have the Google Account image/avatar. Concerning to the specs from http://www.axschema.org/types it should be 'media/image/default' or 'media/image/aspect11' but none of them work :(

Isn't it possible to access the image/avatar via OpenID?
Is the AX type something else?
Is there any other possibility to get that image?

Answer (score 5):

According to the [Google Federated Login](http://code.google.com/intl/pl/apis/accounts/docs/OpenID.html) page, Google supports only the following AX attributes:

- http://axschema.org/contact/country/home
- http://axschema.org/contact/email
- http://axschema.org/namePerson/first
- http://axschema.org/pref/language
- http://axschema.org/namePerson/last

As you can see, none of these contain user's avatar. So as far as I know, there is no way to get it.

Comment: It seems it's still unavailable as of Aug '12, two years layer, but there's always the possibility to find a way to get the Google+ ID: https://profiles.google.com/s2/photos/profile/[ID]?sz=[Size in pixels] . The ID format is XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX where X are digits, and is visible when checking google+ posts.